# Is there a way to simplify this query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is the query I wrote, it has the same couple of lines two times. How can I avoid this?

```
SELECT
    artistID, bio
FROM
    UserReactionToArtistView
WHERE
    genre = 'classical' AND type = 'like' AND bio LIKE '%Rerum%'
GROUP BY
    artistID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = ( SELECT MAX(num) as max
                 FROM 
                   (
                     SELECT
                         artistID, bio, count(*) as num
                     FROM
                         UserReactionToArtistView
                     WHERE
                         genre = 'classical' and type = 'like' AND bio LIKE '%Rerum%'
                     GROUP BY
                         artistID ) as Artists
                    )
```

Sorry if this is formatted poorly or not the place to ask.

Comment: I would think that you would get a sql error on "bio" not being a part of the query you aliased as Artists, you selected it but you did not group or aggregate on it. Does it compile?

Comment: If the field Artists
 .bio is not important than you could fold this rather easily, however, the devil is in the details.

Comment: this does compile and bio is important

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to filter your most inner query by those rows that have **max value** on the `num` column, I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    Artists.artistID,
    Artists.bioo
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            artistID,
            -- Next line can be replaced by ANY_VALUE(bio) on newer versions of MySQL.
            MAX(bio) AS bioo,
            count(*) AS num
        FROM
            UserReactionToArtistView
        WHERE
            genre = 'classical'
        AND
            type = 'like'
        AND
            bio LIKE '%Rerum%'
        GROUP BY
            artistID ) AS Artists
WHERE
    Artists.num = (SELECT MAX(num) FROM Artists);
```

Comment: The artists alias is not in scope somewhere in this query. Which annoys me because that's what I tried first. I checked and its the outer WHERE section, it says that the Artists table does not exists. But aren't queries evaluated inside out, and it should be defined there?

Comment: Well, I was on the hope that the query works. Try replacing `WHERE Artists.num = (SELECT MAX(num) FROM Artists)` by `HAVING Artists.num = MAX(Artists.num)`. If that works, i will update my answer, just letme know.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    artistID, bio
FROM
    UserReactionToArtistView
WHERE
    genre = 'classical' AND type = 'like' AND bio LIKE '%Rerum%'
GROUP BY artistID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It seems to me this is your intention, though that's not exactly the same query, I suppose there can be more than 1 results with the same `COUNT(*)`.

In the case you are expecting multiple results, you can just remove the `LIMIT` and select `COUNT(*)` too, and then iterate through the results until `COUNT(*)` changes.

Either way it should be less expensive than that abomination of a query.

Comment: Just a tip: selecting `bio` that way can produce an error on engines that use the option [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by). If we assume, `bio` have the same value for equals `artistID`, we could add it to the `GROUP BY` clause or use some aggregate function over it on the select clause.

Comment: @D.Smania Well noone in their right mind uses that, and that's why neither the original query, my query, or even your proposed query is bothering to comply with that, so I don't know why you are pointing that out.

Comment: Was just a tip, because MySQL versions over 5.7 have that option enabled by default and when I faced this problem it took me some time to figure it out (just trying to let you know about this). On my answer, I do take care of that, using an aggregate method `MAX()` over the `bio` column.

Comment: I am required to use full group by, but this doesn't break that in mySQL workbench. What did you mean by iterate until the count changes?

Comment: @ShaneMurphy If you remove the `LIMIT` the query will return all results, though listing the artists with more matches first. Your original query will only return the artists with the highest number of matches (there can be more than one with same count). That means that in order to obtain the same outcome, you just have to iterate the rows until you find one with a  `COUNT(*)` that is smaller than the previous one.